# find the unmatched elements at each index in two arrays

Tags: c, algorithm, search

Suppose I have two arrays below (same length), the array is not sorted (randomly):

```
a[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 11}
b[] = {1, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11}
```

May I know what's the fastest way to find **all** the unmatched (different) values between these two arrays? (the index information is enough). Many thanks for your time.

Comment: given values are sorted in array ?

Comment: How large can the arrays be? Do we have a restriction on space complexity? Can we modify the original arrays given as arguments?

Comment: How do you define "unmatched". Are those unmatched elements the ones with values that do not exist in the other array, or is it simply the elements at each index i at which a[i] != b[i]?

Comment: @sunkuet02 Thanks for your reply. The array consists of random numbers, unsorted.

Comment: @ilim Thanks for your reply. Simply the elements at each index.

Comment: @ilim Thanks for your reply. There is no restriction on space complexity. You may modify the original arrays given as arguments.

Comment: naive solution: Search every element and in a zero initialized temp array do temp[a[i]]++ then again temp[b[i]]++. temp's 1's are your elements

Comment: @k_kaz unless your range of values is too high. (e.g. a[i], b[i] < 10^9)

Comment: also, there may be 2 of an element in A and none of it in B..I'd say that would still be unmatched in that case

Comment: @ilim Thanks for your reply. I assume these two arrays have the same length.

Comment: @HuangJie Can you tell us which elements are the unmatched ones in the example you provided?

Comment: @ilim Thanks for your reply. The 2th and the 5th elements are the unmatched ones.

Comment: @HuangJie I tried to provide a possible solution for your question, but it was downvoted. If my solution is incorrect, do let me know how your problem differs from what I understood it to be.

Comment: @HuangJie You may want to consider changing the title of your question to "efficiently comparing elements of two array at same indices" or something. The way it currently is, it is a bit confusing to get a handle on your original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only interested in the indices which correspond to cells with different values in arrays a and b, just iterating through both arrays and checking whether their indices are equal would be sufficient. The parameter **N** given below indicates the size of the arrays a and b.

```
int get_unmatched_indices(int a[], int b[], int N, int indices[])
{
    int i, num_unmatched = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (a[i] != b[i])
        {
            indices[num_unmatched++] = i;
        }
    }
    return num_unmatched;
}
```

The function above finds out the information you seek using **O(N)** extra space (for the indices) and **O(N)** time. If you then want to print the unmatching elements at the found indices, you can iterate over indices and print the values of each a[indices[X]] and b[indices[X]].

**Explanation on whether a better efficiency could be achieved:**

Any approach depending on comparing the values of the elements in a and b require you to read each element in a and b. This can trivial to prove by contradiction. Assume that you can skip comparing the values of a[i] and b[i] at an index i. Then, there is no way of you to know whether a[i] and b[i] are unmatched elements or not, as an indispensable bit of information is skipped.

Now, there are certain problem categories where some approaches better than comparison-based algorithms exist. Sorting is an example. There are comparison-based sorting algorithms, which are at best **O(NlogN)**, but there are also other algorithms that have **O(N)** complexity, with other certain restrictions. So, theoretically it may seem as if there is some non-comparison-based approach that could work. However, even in those algorithms, you would at least need to process all the essential information. (i.e. traverse each element and process it to some form) So even then you already reach to **O(N)** complexity. So any algorithm you may devise could provide a constant factor of efficiency, at best.

Comment: He said the arrays are not sorted, don't assume they are just because the example happens to be

Comment: @ilim Your approach works for the idea. But could there be a faster way to do it? Because the array can be very long. Yes, the arrays are not sorted.

Comment: @Leeor I didn't. In the comments below the post OP compares the elements at the same indices. (i.e. when it's said that the elements at 2nd and 5th indices are the answer) There is an ambiguity in the question statement caused by the term unmatched pushing almost all of us to think in terms of each value having a duplicate in the other array although OP does not imply that in the question.

Comment: @HuangJie In a minute or two, I will try and add to my response an explanation as to why it is not possible to achieve a time complexity better than **O(N)**.

Comment: Then I agree the question is poorly described and the example is confusing, I guess whoever downvoted also thought of the arrays as sets of values, otherwise the problem is trivial. Looks like you're right, here's a +1 :)

Comment: Yeah I'll take my answer down, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @HuangJie done. Hope it is relatively straightforward to understand.

Comment: Does this solution handle *unsorted* array?

Comment: @SauravSahu please read the comments in the original post. There, HuangJie mentioned that only the elements at index i are compared. So, the order of magnitude of the elements in each array are irrelevant to OP's original problem. It's just all of us reading too much into the term *unmatched*.